# Is there a trick to add an unix user with '@' inside its login on debian

Tags: linux, debian, unix, user-accounts, special-characters

On Debian, there is not a lot of limitations to add an unix user. Ie: the login may contain dots and uppercase letters.

Is there a trick to add an unix user with an '@' inside its login ? I understand that @ has a special meaning but is there a workaround ?

As told in comments, logins with @ work well except for sendmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really an *issue* to use a `@` symbol in the username. However, it may bring confusion and some adaptations depending on use. For example, if you use `SSH` to connect with that user, you should use :

```
ssh user@stilluser@server
ssh -l user@stilluser server # this syntax works too
```

Instead of a simple :

```
ssh user@server
```

Both `ssh` connections above work. Here is a real example with the first command :

```
hidigoudi@local_machine:~$ ssh user@stilluser@labo
### Server information (Welcome output)
user@stilluser@labo:~$ id
uid=1001(user@stilluser) gid=1001(user@stilluser) groups=1001(user@stilluser)
user@stilluser@labo:~$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-x--- 4 user@stilluser user@stilluser 4096 Jan 14 08:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root           root           4096 Jan 14 08:32 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 user@stilluser user@stilluser  220 Jan 14 08:32 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 user@stilluser user@stilluser 3771 Jan 14 08:32 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 user@stilluser user@stilluser 4096 Jan 14 08:34 .cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 user@stilluser user@stilluser  807 Jan 14 08:32 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 user@stilluser user@stilluser 2606 Jan 14 08:32 .screenrc
drwx------ 2 user@stilluser user@stilluser 4096 Jan 14 08:34 .ssh
user@stilluser@labo:~$
```

By the way, it's totally allowed and describe by the man of `useradd`.

> Usernames may contain only lower and upper case letters, digits,
> underscores, or dashes. They can end with a dollar
> sign. Dashes are not allowed at the beginning of the username. Fully numeric usernames and usernames . or .. are also
> disallowed. It is not recommended to use usernames beginning with . character as their home directories will be hidden
> in the ls output.
>
> On Debian, the only constraints are that usernames must neither start with a dash ('-') nor plus ('+') nor tilde ('~')
> nor contain a colon (':'), a comma (','), or a whitespace (space: ' ', end of line: '\n', tabulation: '\t', etc.). Note
> that using a slash ('/') may break the default algorithm for the definition of the user's home directory.
>
> Usernames may only be up to 32 characters long.

However, I would advise you to use a naming convention like :

```
([a-z_][a-z0-9_-]{0,30})
```

To **prevent any trouble and unexpected behavior**.

Comment: I'd say the *gold portion* of this is in the last recommendation, I'd recommend to use that for filenames too, regardless of OS. Not because you "must", but to alleviate a lot of trouble.

Comment: A connection with an '@' user fails for most servers. Ftp works but not ssh, nor smtp through sendmail. ( cannot vote up )

Comment: I'm sorry to learn that the `ssh` does not work on your side, however, I assure you that I have never had a problem connecting to different servers using the `@` symbol for the username. I updated my answer as an example. - Your `ssh` problem is related to another thing.

Comment: By the way, thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: you're true, ssh is not really an issue. However, even if it's possible to connect by ftp or ssh with such user, it's not possible to use it with thunderbird... I asked another question to change the authentication method. Perhaps using with another tool another list than /etc/passwd would not generate a problem.